# Classify image with pretrained caffemodel in pycaffe

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I want to classify an image with a pretrained model. I have the caffemodel and prototxt files, but when I load the models in caffe for python with

```
net = caffe.Net('/home/me/data/f1.prototxt',
                '/home/me/data/f1.caffemodel',
                caffe.TEST)
```

I am getting the error

```
Check failed: mdb_status == 0 (2 vs. 0) No such file or directory
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550131/check-failed-mdb-status-0-2-vs-0-no-such-file-or-directory) but the example there is for training a model so it doesn't apply in my case. What am I missing here?

The filepaths and permissions are correct.

Comment: it's the same answer as the one you linked to. Look closely at you f1.prototxt file and make sure no "Data" layers were left there by accident

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll up through the log file; there should be an earlier message telling you exactly what file it couldn't open.  Check the path and permissions.  When I get this, it's usually because I invoked `caffe` from the wrong directory.